# Pass value to activity started from intent in preferences?

Tags: android, android-intent, colors, preference

I have a number of Colors that can be set by the user in preferences. For that I have an Activity with a ColorPicker. The problem is don't know how to pass the key of the color being changed to the ColorPicker so it can save it in SharedPreferences.

```
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/pref_text_color"
            >
            <intent android:targetPackage="com.example.android.launcher"
                    android:targetClass="com.example.android.launcher.preferences.ColorPicker" />
            <!-- Pass value "textColor" -->
        </Preference>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data with the Intent to your ColorPicker activity in the following manner:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ColorPickerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("UNIQUE_KEY_FOR_THIS_COLOR_INFORMATION", colorIndex);
```

and retrieve it at your receiving side:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("UNIQUE_KEY_FOR_THIS_COLOR_INFORMATION", -1);
```

where -1 is the default data if no value for that key is found.

Android has a pretty detailed documentation of Intents, which you should go through: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: But cannot it be done through XML? Does this mean I have to use onclick and start the color picker programatically? Thanks

Comment: You cannot start an Intent through XML, but you can trigger a method which will start the Intent. Simply add this attribute to your button's XML: `android:onClick="yourMethodName"`. This method will be called as soon as the button is clicked. And if you're using a View other than a button (TextView, etc.), add an extra attribute to it: `android:clickable="true"`